# Creating a FTP server on ubuntu desktop

Tags: server, ftp

I would like to make a FTP server on a ubuntu desktop. I am unable to make a ubuntu server install for various reasons, but would like to make a small FTP server, so I can connect to it from my router and the internet.

I would also like to run a minecraft server on it, is that possible?

Thank-you in advance.

Comment: Regular FTP or sFTP? (Regular ancient FTP uses plain text passwords - Not recommended).

Answer (score 2):

ftp server can have either anonymous or user authenticated. Check put this [Official Ubuntu 14.04 wiki page](https://help.ubuntu.com/14.04/serverguide/ftp-server.html) for ftp server. Also visit [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-set-up-vsftpd-on-ubuntu-12-04) for step by step guide.